# VS Code extension: how to add something after cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

e.g. user types `$someObject-` then extension adds `>` (same as it does popular plugin for Netbeans).
What kind of contributes/capabilities I must use? There's some good example extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answers after searching and some experiments:

package.json:

```
...
"contributes": {
        "languages": [
            {
              "id": "php",
              "extensions": [".php"],
              "aliases": ["PHP", "php"]
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

And all the fun there's around an event `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`.
I must make something like this:

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    registration = vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(event => {
        const doc = event.document;
        const changes = event.contentChanges[0];
        const { line, character } = changes.range.start;
        const prevPosition = new vscode.Position(line, character - 1);
        const position = new vscode.Position(line, character);
        const newPosition = new vscode.Position(line, character+1);
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        const prevText = doc.getText(new vscode.Range(prevPosition, position));
        if (prevText === "-") {
                editor?.edit(TextEditorEdit => {
                    TextEditorEdit.insert(newPosition, ">");
                });
        }
    });
}
```

This example just always insert `>` after `-`.